# using a variable outside of a function C#

Tags: c#, function, variables, set

I would like to create a variable which uses another variable outside of a function, like this:

```
private void tb_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
  ...
}

TextStyle txtstyle = new TextStyle(new SolidBrush(Color.Red), null, FontStyle.Regular); // the variable

private void tb_VisibleRangeChangedDelayed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ...
}
```

I want to replace Color.Red in txtstyle with a custom color which is in the applications setting. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why do you want it done this way? Can you not declare the variable and initialize it in a constructor with the values you want?

Comment: Why you've provided two methods? You want to change text style once or in each function call?

Comment: I just provided the methods to show that the variable is outside of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the settings in this way:

```
TextStyle txtstyle = new TextStyle(new SolidBrush(Properties.Settings.Default["Color"]), null, FontStyle.Regular); // the variable
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted, and it's very simple too.

Answer (score 4):

I would create a private property like this:

```
private TextStyle myTextStyle
    {
        get
        {
            var colorName = "Red";

            if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myColor"]))
            {
                colorName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myColor"];
            }

            return new TextStyle(new SolidBrush(Color.FromName(colorName)), null, FontStyle.Regular);
        }
    }
```

you have to add a reference to System.Configuration for this to work.

Comment: Took me awhile to fully understand his question as asked, but from what I could figure out, this is exactly what he's looking for.

Comment: Yes, however since the code posted by Fischermaen is more shorter, I have used his one instead.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have declared `txtstyle` in the class scope, you can access it from within functions that are part of the same class.

I suggest you read up on [C# scoping rules](http://people.iola.dk/arj/2009/01/02/scoping-rules-in-c/).

Comment: **I want to replace Color.Red in txtstyle ...** seems to be missing

Comment: I thought he is asking as how to replace the Color from the App settings

Comment: @V4Vendetta - That's not my reading. My understanding is that the Color is _initialized_ from config, but he then wants to change it during runtime, not to change the config.